# creating a sub string from a string array-list

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that contains names and phone numbers in the following format:

me-11111 ,
 you-22222 ,
 we-33333 ,
 us-44444 ,
 they-55555 ,

after I store the above in an array-list, I want to create a method that first asks the user to enter a name and then check if the name exists. If yes, then print out the corresponding number.

here is what I have:

```
public static void search () {
        String wanted;
        System.out.println("Give a neme: ");
        wanted = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++)
        { 
            // here I'm trying to separate the names in the array-list
            // if it matches "wanted" print it out
            if (wanted.equals(list.get(i).substring(' ', ','))) {
                System.out.println("names: " + list.get(i));
            }
        }
}
```

I'm getting this **error**, what is the cause

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 44

Comment: Convert this into a `Map<String, String>` while reading in and your problem is solved.

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate

Comment: Does such a substring method exists with these parameters?substring(' ', ',')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindString {
    public static List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        names.add("me-22222");
        names.add("us-33333");
        names.add("you-44444");
        names.add("they-55555");

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String toCheck = scanner.next();

        for(String s : names) {
            String[] parts = s.split("-");
            String name = parts[0]; 
            int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            if(toCheck.equals(name))
                System.out.println("This name already got a number : " + number);
            else 
                System.out.println("There is no number connected with this name!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner will ask you 3 times for input. Change that number and you will see difference. Let me know if u got it! @zamzam

Comment: This is nice tutorial but not what I wanted. I already have a list of names and numbers as mentioned in the question. Now I want to ask the user to enter a name, if the name matches any of the names in the list, then, print out their number.

Comment: But what are numbers associated with that names? @zamzam

Comment: hmm you know you are probably right but I dont understand your solution. what I had in mind was to iterate through the string array-list, separate the names, see if they match the wanted name, if yes, then print out the number in front of them after the "-"

Comment: Is this ok? @zamzam

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. yes this is what I wanted to do

Comment: it throws this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" at this line: int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
// here when read every line from file, split the line with "-"
// and store it in the map
String[] strs = line.split("-");
users.put(strs[0], strs[1]);

// then when you check, you can do as below
if (users.containsKey(name)) {
    System.out.println("Phone: "+users.get(name));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answers. is "line" a string as the line in the question above?

Answer (score 0):

Most problem will have a very simple solution in code when data is represented in a way that aids solving the problem. In your case represent the data as a `Map<String, String>` from name to number and it will be trivial to check for existence and lookup:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String data = "me-012345, them-543210";
    Map<String, String> name2number = new HashMap<>();
    for (String entry: data.split(", ")) {
        String[] pair = entry.split("-");
        name2number.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

    System.out.println(name2number.get("me"));
    System.out.println(name2number.get("them"));
    System.out.println(name2number.get("somebody else"));
}
```

This test prints:

```
012345
543210
null
```

In essence, when you read in or load the data in the format described above, parse them immediately, place in a matching structure (`Map` or `MultiMap` if multiple numbers for the same name possible) and structure your code around this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to do this. Based on your simple way, I correct it as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) { 
    String temp = list.get(i);
    if (wanted.equals(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('-')))) {
        System.out.println("names: " + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the code to read content from File. To make sure that you did right in that part. I have written a complete demo for your reference.

Read user's name and phone number into a `Map` is a Comprehensible way. No need to write loop yourself to get user's phone number but let `Map` to send it to you.

Please see the code below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        readFile();
        search();
    }

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void readFile(){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1"));
            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line != null){
                String tokens[] = line.split(" ,");
                for(String token: tokens){
                    String name = token.split("-")[0].trim();
                    String phoneNum = token.split("-")[1].trim();
                    map.put(name, phoneNum);
                }

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
                System.out.println(map);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void search() {
        String wanted;
        System.out.println("Give a neme: ");
        wanted = scan.nextLine();

        if(map.get(wanted) != null){
            System.out.println("names: " + map.get(wanted));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Name is not existed");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is beginning index and lastIndex of subString method.
Take a look at this it works fine.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    populateNameList();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    search(name);
}

private static void populateNameList(){
    nameList.add("me-11111");
    nameList.add("you-22222");
    nameList.add("we-33333");
    nameList.add("us-44444");
}

 private static void search(String name){
    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameList.get(i).substring(0,
                nameList.get(i).indexOf("-")))){
            System.out.println(nameList.get(i).substring(nameList.get(i).indexOf("-")+1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```